# How can I configure my Sentelic touchpad to scroll more slowly?

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I just bought an MSI CR640-035US laptop computer with a Sentelic touchpad. The touchpad's "page slider" option works in a frustrating way: sliding my finger up and down on the right side of the touchpad makes pages fly by just as if I was using the `page up` and `page down` buttons. The double finger scroll gesture that they offer does the same thing. The slow/fast level slider doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way to get it to scroll up/down just a little when I move my finger up/down just a little instead of jumping by page?

I can use the "Vertical Scrolling" option which means I can hold my finger on the top right or bottom right corners of my touchpad and it will auto scroll a predetermined speed until I let go. That is also not what I want.

[image: Screenshot of "Finger Sensing Pad Configurator" Dialogue box]

Comment: Have you tried changing the Mouse scroll speed in Control Panel?

Comment: @Steve Yeah, that unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Anyone else figured this out? The Sentelic touchpad just *jumps* like PgUp / PgDn rather than scrolling smoothly..